Как правильнее разделять компоненты приложения на воркер ноды
Осваиваю развертывание инфраструктуры в Kubernetes вместе с Docker. Правильно ли держать БД в воркер ноде вместе с приложением или правильнее на отдельной воркер ноде размещать контейнеры БД? Аналогичный вопрос по RabbitMQ, Redis. Разделяют ли обычно на воркер ноды их либо в поды группируют на одной воркер ноде?
